# Azure App Zip package doesn't have the latest update of minified files in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to deploy my app using [Run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package).

***Run a target before publishing***
[image]

***Screenshot of the tasks to zip and publish aircraft***
[image]

***Screenshot of gulp min command***
[image]

From the task, I can see the gulp min is executed before zipped the file. But somehow the minified js, CSS doesn't have the latest/updated content

Looking for some help, if there is anything need to be corrected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot of task log, the gulp min command has  executed and the working directory is Source Folder instead of Artifacts folder.

In this case, the changed files will existing in `$(Build.Sourcesdirectory)`

To update the files in Artifacts directory, you can use [Copy files Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the updated minified files to artifacts and zip the files for deployment.

For example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Sourcesdirectory)/minfilefolder'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Comment: I tried to add the copy file task after Generate Deployment task. But still the copied files doesn't have the latest/updated content

Comment: I have tried to read the content of minified file from `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`, But its not latest code as well.